# Can not install shinyTable successfully

Tags: r, github, shiny

I followed the instruction on the Github. It returned me an error like this:

```
install_github("shinyTable", "trestletech")
Downloading github repo trestletech/shinyTable@master
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
Timeout was reached
 In addition: Warning message:
 Username parameter is deprecated. Please use trestletech/shinyTable
```

Then, I tried to download the repo zip file and installed the shinyTable from local zip file in R studio. After that, I library(shinyTable). It return me an error.

```
> install.packages("D:/UserData/xxxx/Downloads/shinyTable-master.zip", repos = NULL)
Installing package into ‘D:/UserData/xxxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
> library(shinyTable)
Error in library(shinyTable) : there is no package called ‘shinyTable’
```

This is sessionInfo() result:

```
R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shinyRGL_0.1.0 devtools_1.8.0 rJava_0.9-7   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] rgl_0.95.1247   Rcpp_0.12.0     digest_0.6.8    mime_0.3        R6_2.1.0        xtable_1.7-4    git2r_0.10.1   
 [8] magrittr_1.5    httr_1.0.0      stringi_0.5-5   curl_0.9.2      xml2_0.1.1      tools_3.2.1     stringr_1.0.0  
[15] shiny_0.12.2    httpuv_1.3.3    rversions_1.0.2 htmltools_0.2.6 tcltk_3.2.1     memoise_0.2.1
```

Does anyone know the reason and tell me how to install it? Thank you.

Comment: The zipped repo will not be recognized as a proper package. Can you add to your question the result of a `sessionInfo()` ?

Comment: @Vincent Guillemot I added sessionInfo(). I use the same way to install shingRGL, it is OK but i failed to install shinyTable. If you know the reason, could you also tell me how to install it? Thank you.

Comment: Try to just unzip "shinyTable-master.zip" and use the command `install.packages("D:/UserData/xxxx/Downloads/shinyTable-master", repos = NULL)`. It worked on Ubuntu, I'm going to try it on Windows right now.

Comment: @Vincent Guillemot Mine is windows. I tried it but I got an error: Error in install.packages : type == "both" cannot be used with 'repos = NULL'

Comment: Well, it did not work. However, the following command worked on Windows: `install.packages("D:/UserData/xxxx/Downloads/shinyTable-master", repos = NULL, type="source")`.

Comment: I ran the new one but still error:

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87010/discussion-between-vincent-guillemot-and-cutebunny).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar issues recently.  Can you try this:

```
library(devtools)
install_git("https://github.com/trestletech/shinyTable")
```